# Android 4.2.2 back button issue

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have developed a custom launcher for android. The launcher is working fine except for a 'bug' that it has.

I have given the user certain shortcuts on the main screen for accessibility.

Now suppose the user starts the Youtube activity. When the user presses the back button it goes back to the launcher, which is fine.

I am invoking the activity like this

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
context.startActivity(manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(youtubeactivitystring));
```

I have also provided a shortcut to a browser activity for help on the main screen which is invoked as follows:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://url/content/help"));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

When the user clicks on HELP he is unable to get out of the browser (it's stuck there for some reason). When the user clicks the HOME button, the user lands on the launcher. When the user goes back to start another activity (say youtube again) and then get out the activity by clicking the BACK button, somehow the browser activity opens. I am unable to understand why is this happening.

Please help